# Displaying date between two dates without ( IIf and Citeria)

Tags: ms-access

I'm new to access and coding so please bear with me.
I want my [Exp] dates that fall between 1/12/2020 and 1/7/2021 to be shown/displayed in [Exp2] record and if it doesn't fall between the two mentioned dates then show/display nothing in Exp2 record.
Example: |

```
| Exp       | Exp2       |
| 1/5/2020  |            |
| 3/8/2020  |            |
| 12/13/2020| 12.13.2020 |
```

see in Exp2 only 3rd record is shown/displayed while the first and second are empty.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JQbl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htotJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a query like this:

```sql
Select
    [Exp],
    IIf([Exp] Between #2020-12-01# And #2021-07-01#, [Exp], Null) As Exp2
From
    YourTable
```

or use a subquery (slower):

```sql
Select
    [Exp],
        (Select 
            First(T.Exp)
        From 
            YourTable As T
        Where 
            T.Exp = YourTable.Exp 
            And
            T.Exp Between #2020-12-01# And #2021-07-01#) As Exp2
From
    YourTable
```

Comment: i have to do it without IIf.

Comment: And why, please?

Comment: Because that's homework from teacher he said we have to do it without IIf and its easy.
but half a day have gone by and out of 90 students no one have yet to answer it

Comment: I should have figured that out.